# Proxify an application via loopback adapters and SSH

Tags: proxy, socks

This is part programming, part sysadmin, so please excuse me if you feel that this should be over on serverfault.

I have an application that is *not* SOCKS aware and that we need to use through a firewall. We cannot modify the application to have SOCKS support either.

At the moment, we do this by aliasing the IPs the application talks to the loopback adapter on the host, then creating SSH tunnels out to another host.  The IP's the application uses are hardcoded.  Our SSH connections look like:

ssh -L 1.2.3.4:9999:1.2.3.4:9999 user@somehost

Where 1.2.3.x are aliases on the loopback.

So the application connects to the open port on the loopback, which gets sent out to the SSH host and onto the real 1.2.3.4.

It works, but the problem is that this application connects to quite a few IPs ( 50+ ), so we end up with 50 ssh connections out from the box.

We've tried to use several 'proxifying' apps, like tsocks and others but have had alot of issues with them ( the app is running on OS X and tsocks doesn't work so well, even with the patches )

Our idea was to write a daemon that listened on all interfaces on the specified port - it would then take the incoming packets from the application, scrape the packet info ( dst IP, port, payload ), recreate the packet and proxify it through a single SSH SOCKS connection ( ssh -D 1080 user@somehost ).  That way, we only have 1 SSH connection that all the ports are being proxied through.

My question is - is this feasible? Is there something that I'm missing here?  I've been combing through pfctl, ipfw, iptables docs, but I don't see any option to do it through those and this doesn't seem like it'd be the most difficult thing to code.  It would recreate the packet based on the original destination IP and port, connect to the local SOCKs proxy and resend the packet as if it were the original application, but now with SOCKS support.

If I'm missing something that someone knows about that already does this, please let me know.  I don't know socket programming or SOCKs too well, but this doesn't seem like it'd be too big of a project to tackle, but I'd like some opinions if I'm biting off way more that I should.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your application could add SOCKS client support, you can simply `ssh -D lock_socks_port remote_machine`, which will open up the local *lock_socks_port* as a SOCKS server at localhost, which can then connect to any host accesible by the remote machine.

Example: imagine you are using an untrusted wifi network without encryption.  You can simply launch `ssh -D 1082 home`, and then configure your web browser to use *localhost:1080* as SOCKS server.  Of course, you need a SOCKS-enabled client.  All the traffic would appear as coming from your gateway, and the connection would be opaque to those snooping the wifi.

You can also open a single `ssh` client with an indefinite number of `LocalForward` requests, which would be  tunneled on top of a single ssh session.

Moreover, you can add ssh connections to an already-established ssh connection by using the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options of ssh.

Comment: I'll check out the ControlMaster and ControlPath options - we can't modify the application, so there is no opportunity to add SOCKS support to it.  I've modified the original question slightly to better represent our issue.